# When is a de Rham cohomology class the Poincaré dual of the fundamental class of a closed submanifold?

Tags: algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

We know that for any $n$-dimensional orientable manifolds $M$ and a $k$-dimensional closed submanifold $S$ with inclusion map $i:S\to M$, then there is a cohomology class $[S]\in H^{n-k}(M)$ such that for all $\omega\in H^k_c(M)$ we have $$\int_Si^*\omega=\int_M\omega\wedge[S].$$

[Q] Now, given $\tau\in H^{n-k}(M)$, when does there exist a $k$-dimensional closed submanifold $S$ such that $\tau$ and $[S]$ are the same cohomology class?

I think this is wrong. But I have been told that we can solve this problem in some special cases as follows:

We can prove that for a compact complex manifold $X$ and a irreducible hypersurface $D$ (forms a divisor), then we have $c_1(\mathcal{O}(D))=[D]$ where $\mathcal{O}$ is the canonical homomorphism between $\mathrm{Div}(X)$ and $\mathrm{Pic}(X)$ and $[D]$ is the fundamental class of $D$. But how can we use this?

[Some ideas of myself] In the compact Kähler case, use the Lefschetz theorem on $(1,1)$-classes we know that $c_1$ span $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb{Z})$. In projective case, the map $\mathcal{O}:\mathrm{Div}(X)\to\mathrm{Pic}(X)$ is surjective by Kodaira embedding theorem, Serre vanishing and Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch theorem. So in general case if wee saw
$c_1$ as $\mathrm{Pic}(X)\to H^2(X)$, it may not be surjective in many cases!

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I found the original statement of your question to be unclear. I have made some edits to clarify. If I have changed your intended question, feel free to rollback the edit.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Thank you! Maybe I need to fill in some details.